# android - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError On RealmRecycle View

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

i have error on java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.realm.RealmRecyclerViewAdapter$1
i am using realm `compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0'` and `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.1"`
when i am build my RealmAdapter Named : AdapterJadwalKuliahRV

```
public class AdapterJadwalKuliahRV extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<JadwalKuliahModel, AdapterJadwalKuliahRV.MyViewHolder> {



public AdapterJadwalKuliahRV(OrderedRealmCollection<JadwalKuliahModel> data){
    super(data, true);
    setHasStableIds(true);
}



@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_jk, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
    final JadwalKuliahModel jk = getItem(position);
    holder.data= jk;
    holder.txtHari.setText(jk.getHari_jk());
    holder.txtMakul.setText(jk.getMakul_jk());
    holder.txtJam.setText(jk.getWaktu_jk());
    holder.txtDosen.setText(jk.getDosen_jk());
    holder.txtRuangan.setText(jk.getRuangan_jk());
    holder.txtKelas.setText(jk.getKelas_jk());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){ 
   return data.size(); 
}


class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView txtHari,txtMakul,txtJam,txtDosen,txtRuangan,txtKelas;
    private JadwalKuliahModel data;

    private MyViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        txtHari = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowhariJK);
        txtJam = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowJamjk);
        txtMakul = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowMakul);
        txtDosen = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowDosen);
        txtRuangan = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowRuanganjk);
        txtKelas = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowKelasJK);

    }
}
```

and this is ny Method to set that adapter and implements to my activity

```
private void setupRecycler() {
    realm.getDefaultInstance();
    AdapterJadwalKuliahRV = new AdapterJadwalKuliahRV(realm.where(JadwalKuliahModel.class).findAll());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(AdapterJadwalKuliahRV);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

}
```

and this is my Model

```
private static AtomicInteger INTEGER_COUNTER = new AtomicInteger(0);


@PrimaryKey
private int no_jk;

private String hari_jk;
private String waktu_jk;
private String makul_jk;
private String ruangan_jk;
private String dosen_jk;
private String kelas_jk, created_at, updated_at;
private String Author;
private int noonline_j;
final static public String jkSort ="";

public JadwalKuliahModel() {
}

public JadwalKuliahModel(int no_jk, String hari_jk, String waktu_jk, String makul_jk, String ruangan_jk, String dosen_jk, String kelas_jk, String created_at, String updated_at, String author, int noonline_j) {
    this.no_jk = no_jk;
    this.hari_jk = hari_jk;
    this.waktu_jk = waktu_jk;
    this.ruangan_jk = ruangan_jk;
    this.makul_jk = makul_jk;
    this.dosen_jk = dosen_jk;
    this.kelas_jk = kelas_jk;
    this.created_at = created_at;
    this.updated_at = updated_at;
    this.Author = author;
    this.noonline_j = noonline_j;
}
```

with Setter And Getter

but, i have problem with RealmRecyclerViewAdapter
like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TterF.png)

please help me..

Comment: Do you add apply plugin for realm? Try to clean and rebuild project. Need more information to solve this problem.

Comment: sure i have. i have apply realm plugin in gradle

Answer (score 1):

`compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0'` supports only Realm-Java 3.0.0 and above (for example the current latest, which is `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.1.2"`).

To use `realm-android-adapters` with Realm 2.x, you need to use `compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.5.0`.

You are getting this exception because `OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener` does not exist before Realm 3.0.0